# Why perspiration drops are seen in shopping bag?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, water, evaporation

Why perspiration drops are seen in shopping bag?
When i put hot bread in shopping bag after sometime i saw perspiration drops in the shopping bag.

Comment: Condensation of water vapor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation

Comment: Water evaporates from the bread and condenses on the bag.